# How to avoid black dots and green worms on a lettuce?

Tags: leaves, containers, worms

Just a week ago, I planted a young letuce in a small pot in my second-floor window. Today, I found these black dots:

[image]

plus three big green worms (not shown). I have no idea how they got into the second floor. Some of the leaves are eaten - probably by the worms. What can I do to save my letuce?

EDIT: it seems what I saw was a [cabbage looper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabbage_looper).

Answer (score 1):

Limited choices for food crops. The only one I know is BT ( bacillius thurgensis) , which is commonly available . It kills insects and is safe for any mammal and most other animals . It can be used in ponds to kill mosquitos but does not harm fish. Malathion can be used but then you must wait about a month after use ( time used to be a week , but that is politically incorrect now ).